# Good practice and memory leaks

Tags: c, dynamic

```
int* difference (int *a, int *b){
    if (*a > *b){
    *a = *a - *b;
    }else{
        *a = *b - *a;
    }
    return a;
}

int main (){
    int *xp, *yp;
    int x, y;

    x = 9;
    y = 7;

    xp = &x;
    yp = &y;

    xp = difference (xp,yp);
    printf("xp value: %d\n", *xp);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reasons I need my program to do some mathematical operations on mono dimensional arrays. I posted a sample here because I'm concerned regarding the difference function and its returned value.

The both values are pointers but I need to do this because I can't know for sure which of the values is grater. Is my way of doing things a good practice or is there a better way for this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what is the question. And I imagine the call to `sum(xp,yp)` should really be `xp=difference(xp,yp);`

Comment: What does this have to do with memory leaks ?

Comment: What is the problem here? Do you happen to have an issue with this code?

Comment: The code works just fine. I want to know if there is a good practice to use pointers in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, i try to avoid pointers as possible or, if not, always check null pointers. In this case, I would modify `difference()` by:

```
int difference (int a, int b){
    if (a > b){
       return a - b:
    return b - a;
}
```

With this new way, you doesn't need to check null values:

```
int* difference (int *a, int *b){
    if (a && b)
    {
        if (*a > *b){
           *a = *a - *b;
        }else{
           *a = *b - *a;
        }
        return a;
    }

    // and what must I do with null pointers???????
}
```

Besides, in main function, you doesn't need to create pointers from int:

```
int main (){
    int x, y;

    x = 9;
    y = 7;

    x = sum (x, y);
    printf("xp value: %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

In resume, try to avoid pointers if not necessary or, if not, always check null values

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd use pointers here.  Your `difference()` function always assigns the difference to `*a`, and always returns `a`.  You may as well just take two `int` parameters and return an `int` -- this will work fine.

As it is, even if you don't assign the return from `difference()` to anything, the value pointed to by `a` is modified.  Assigning the return value to the same pointer variable you passed as the `a` parameter is unnecessary -- you're setting it to the same value it already had.  What it *points* at is modified in the function, through `a`, regardless.

A non-pointer version:

```
int difference(int a, int b)
{
  if (a > b)
    return a - b;
  else
    return b - a;
}
```

Or the same thing but shorter:

```
int difference(int a, int b)
{
  return (a > b) ? (a - b) : (b - a);
}
```

Then instead of

```
xp = difference(xp,yp);
```

you'd use

```
x = difference(x,y);
```

Or, with `xp` and `yp`:

```
*xp = difference(*xp,*yp);
```

Remember that you don't need to make your function parameters pointers just to use the values inside the function.  You only need pointers when you want to modify variables that are *outside* your function, other than by assigning your function's return value to them.  Since you're always modifying just one variable here, you can just assign the function's return value to it instead of modifying it through a pointer within the function.  All the stuff inside the function works just fine with the copies passed as arguments -- it doesn't need pointers to the original variables, and with simple types like `int` passing pointers instead of just the values would be less efficient anyway...  though with bigger types like large `struct`s sometimes passing pointers is better even when you don't strictly need to.